# Splitting paragraph of separate text file into separate strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, visual-c++

I would like some advice/help in regards to splitting up a paragraph from a separate text file into their own strings. The code I have so far just counts the total amount of words in that paragraph but I would like to split it so each line is 1 sentence then count how many words are in that sentence/line then put that into its' own array so I can do other things with that specific sentience/line. Here is what I have code wise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
 std::ifstream inFile;
 inFile.open("Rhymes.txt", std::ios::in);
 if (inFile.is_open())
 {
     string word;
     unsigned long wordCount = 0;

     while (!inFile.eo())
     {
        inFile >> word;
        if (word.length() > 0)
        {
            wordCount++;
        }
     }

     cout << "The file had " << wordCount << " word(s) in it." << endl;
 } 


 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

The separate text file is called "Rhymes.txt" and that contains:

```
Today you are You, that is truer than true. There is no one alive who is Youer than You.
The more that you read, the more things you will know. The more that you learn, the more places you'll go.
How did it get so late so soon? Its night before its afternoon.
Today was good. Today was fun. Tomorrow is another one.
And will you succeed? Yes indeed, yes indeed! Ninety-eight and three-quarters percent guaranteed!
Think left and think right and think low and think high. Oh, the things you can think up if only you try!
Unless someone like you cares a whole awful lot, nothing is going to get better. It's not.
I'm sorry to say so but, sadly it's true that bang-ups and hang-ups can happen to you.
```

So the first line would be its own sentence and when the code is executed it would say:

```
The line has 19 words in it
```

I am a bit confused as too how I would go about doing this. I have seen examples of splitting sentences into words but I couldn't find anything that I could really understand that had to do with what I am asking for.

Comment: It's "separate", not "seperate".

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that each white space is exactly one blank character, and there is no plenking/klemping, you can count via `std::count`. Reading in the lines can be done via `std::getline`.

```
int main()
{
    // Simulating the file:
    std::istringstream inFile(
R"(Today you are You, that is truer than true. There is no one alive who is Youer than You.
The more that you read, the more things you will know. The more that you learn, the more places you'll go.
How did it get so late so soon? Its night before its afternoon.
Today was good. Today was fun. Tomorrow is another one.
And will you succeed? Yes indeed, yes indeed! Ninety-eight and three-quarters percent guaranteed!
Think left and think right and think low and think high. Oh, the things you can think up if only you try!
Unless someone like you cares a whole awful lot, nothing is going to get better. It's not.
I'm sorry to say so but, sadly it's true that bang-ups and hang-ups can happen to you.)");

    std::vector<std::string> lines; // This vector will contain all lines.

    for (std::string str; std::getline(inFile, str, '\n');)
    {
        std::cout << "The line has "<< std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ')+1 <<" words in it\n";
        lines.push_back(std::move(str)); // Avoid the copy.
    }

    for (auto const& s : lines)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

If you need the amount of words in each sentence later on, save an `std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>` to save both the line and the word count - alter the loop body to this:

```
        std::size_t count = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ') + 1;
        std::cout << "The line has "<<count<<" words in it\n";
        lines.emplace_back(std::move(str), count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like:

```
vector<string> read_line()
{  string line, w;
   vector<string> words;

   getline(cin, line);
   stringstream ss(line);

   while(ss >> w)
     words.push_back(w);

   return words;
}
```

The returned vector contains the information you need: count of words and the words themselves (with punctuation which you can remove easily).

```
vector<string> words = read_line();
cout << "This line has " << words.size() << " words in it" << endl;
```

To read all lines you do:

```
while(1)
{  vector<string> words = read_line();
   if(words.size() == 0) break;

   // process line
}
```